# Ruby on Rails ApplicationController.rb accepts neither < nor =

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, superclass

I have this problem which when I run the rake db:migrate from Heroku via the command
    'heroku run rake db:migrate'

```
/app/app/assets/controllers/application_controller.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected =, expecting '<' or ';' or '\n'
```

When I change the '=' to '<'

I get the error:

```
/app/app/assets/controllers/application_controller.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected <, expecting '=' or ';' or '\n'
```

Any help is appreciated
Feel free to ask for any addition files needed

Comment: What does ApplicationController.rb look like?

Comment: class ApplicationController = ApplicationController
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end

Comment: Hi just remove application controller content and retype by hand

Comment: This is the file from app/assets/controllers/applicationcontroller.rb

Comment: @Mohanraj The content of the applicationcontroller.rb is default as when the app was started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `application_controller.rb` file should look like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception. 
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead. 
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception 
end
```

The less than symbol is used for class inheritance in Ruby.

http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_inheritance.html

Less than or equal to and just equal to have no native usage between classes in Ruby. You can, by the way, test for inheritance using less than:

```
class A; end

class B < A; end

if B < A
  puts "B inherits from A"
end
```

Comment: Isn't ApplicationController and ApplicationController the same?

Comment: Thanks for catching that.